# Modifying large data set that is bound to DataGridView takes a long time?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview

I have a custom object (MyObject) that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has three properties (one int, one string and one bool).  Here's the code for that object:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private int _Index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return _Index; }
        set
        {
            if (_Index == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Index = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Index"));
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Name = value;
            _Modified = true;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private bool _Modified;
    public bool Modified
    {
        get { return _Modified; }
        set
        {
            if (_Modified == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Modified = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Modified"));
        }
    }

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public MyObject(int index, string number, bool modified)
    {
        Index = index;
        Number = number;
        Modified = modified;
    }
}
```

To make a long story short, I have a BindingList of these objects hooked up to a DataGridView like this:

```
BindingList<MyObject> myObjectList = new BindingList<MyObject>();
BindingSource bindingSourceForMyObjects = new BindingSource();

bindingSourceForMyObjects.DataSource = myObjectList;
dataGridViewMyObjects.DataSource = bindingSourceForMyObjects;
```

When my application runs, myObjectList will be populated with 100,000 objects (read from a file) and displayed in my DataGridView.  I only have a single column in the DataGridView which displays the string property for my objects.  It's possible that my user may want to select all rows in the DataGridView and "delete" them.  I use quotes around the term delete because the objects don't actually get deleted but rather the string property of all 100,000 objects gets set to string.Empty.  Right now, I perform that operation using this code:

```
myObjectList.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Name = string.Empty);
```

This operation takes ~ 55 seconds to complete.  I've also tried:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewMyObjects.SelectedRows)
{
    row.Cells["NAME"].Value = string.Empty;
}
```

This takes slightly less time at 49 seconds but it's still a long operation.  On a side note, I also have a ListChanged event handler defined for bindingSourceForMyObjects like this:

```
private void bindingSourceForMyObjects_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
        dataGridViewMyObjects.Rows[e.NewIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridViewMyObjects.Rows[e.NewIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using this to visually indicate a row that has been changed in the DataGridView when I programatically make a change to my underlying list of objects (as I do when I set them all to string.Empty).  This does add some overhead when I "delete" all of the objects but even without this event handler, it's still a lengthy operation.

Lastly, my WinForms application is currently single-threaded but I'm planning to multithread code that makes sense to do so.  This operation may be one of those cases, but before I go down that road, is there anything else I'm missing (or doing that I don't need to be doing) which would improve the performance of this operation so it doesn't take almost a minute to complete?  Or is that just the nature of dealing with 100,000 objects?

Comment: Can you break down the time spent in the `.ToList()` vs the time spent in the `.ForEach(c => ...)`?

Comment: Also does the `c.Name` property do anything in its setter or is just an auto-property?

Comment: .ToList() takes < .005 seconds.  The rest of the time is spent in the .ForEach().  With regard to c.Name, the only thing it's setter does, aside from assigning the value, is to set the bool property of the object to true (I'm using the bool property to track which objects are dirty and need to be flushed to disk).

Comment: Is the for-loop performance similar in a console app (ie, outside of the gui)?

Comment: Can you post your code for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation? Where are you raising the event from?  I have just done a quick test using the code above, and I can update roughly 250k rows in a matter of seconds.  The `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation may be causing a slow down.

Comment: @AustinSalonen yes, the loop performance is basically the same (+/- 1 or 2 seconds)

Comment: @Kami ok, I updated the question to include the object class

Comment: For what it's worth, unhooking the ListChanged event handler for my BindingSource cuts about 8 seconds off of the operation but that still leaves me with a total time of ~46 seconds and I lose the code that changes the colors of each row to indicate that they've been modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@User685869 Thanks for posting the extended object.

After having done some quick test examples, it seems that raising the `PropertyChanged` event is causing the slow down. Removing calls to it will cause the operation to complete within a second or two for 100k records on my pc.

This will occur even if there is no handler for the event.

I presume you have implemented the interface as you need it; if you don't then removing it will resolve your issue.

The only solution that I can suggest is to create a `boolean` variable that you can set to true to prevent the event from being raised when you are doing bulk updates and switch back to normal after.  The downside of this is ofcourse there are no events raised when doing the bulk operation.

for example :-

MyObject

```
public boolean bulk = false;
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (_Name == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Name = value;
        _Modified = true;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
    }
}
```

Parent Code

```
_bindingList.ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
       c.bulk = true;
       c.Name = string.Empty;
       c.bulk = false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I can make something like that work.  More often than not, I just need changes made in the DataGridView pushed back to the list of objects.  There are a few circumstances that caused me to add two-way binding via INotifyPropertyChanged but I may be able to work around those with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
        //do changes
        dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really improve performance for me much.  It did shave ~1.5 seconds off of my previously stated times, though.  Thank you for the suggestion.